# Return current time and Day SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, time

My SQL table looks like this:

```
IN_Time     Day         Name
21:00       Monday      Adam781;
22:15       Tuesday     Adam952;
23:45       Friday      Adam253;
...
```

I want the query to return the name if {current day && current time} matches `Day` and `In_time` column.

e.g So if today is Tuesday and time is 22:15(irrespective of date), query should return `Adam952`

Below is what I tried, but can't figure out how to add `Day` as well

```
SELECT Name FROM test_table
WHERE In_Time IN (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), GETDATE(), 108)+':00');
```

Also, please let me know if there is a better way to select current time(in hh:mm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
SELECT Name
FROM test_table
WHERE DAY = DATENAME(weekday, GETDATE()) AND
      INTIME = CONVERT(TIME, GETDATE())
```

Note that this answers your question, but the time needs to match exactly.  If you just want the hours and minutes to match:

```
SELECT Name
FROM test_table
WHERE DAY = DATENAME(weekday, GETDATE()) AND
      DATEPART(HOUR, INTIME) = DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE()) AND
      DATEPART(MINUTE, INTIME) = DATEPART(MINUTE, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 1):

You also need to compare `[day]` column with today.

```
SELECT Name
FROM [test_table]
WHERE IN_Time  = CONVERT(varchar(8),getdate(),8) 
and [day] = datename(weekday,getdate());
```